# Creating a custom template, based on some existing LXC template after running the instance at least once

Tags: lxc, lxd

(Please note that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258164/5462) is about LXC 1.x, whereas *this one* is about LXC 2.x/LXD)

I scoured the web for an answer to this one, but couldn't come up with any reasonably non-hacky answer.

What I am looking for is an approach to fashion an existing template a way I'd like to. In particular what I'm after is to customize the upstream Ubuntu cloud image by making various changes in its root FS and adding/changing configuration.

So my current approach is to `lxc launch ubuntu:lts CONTAINER` and then use `lxc exec CONTAINER -- ...` to run a script I authored (after pushing it into the container) to perform my customizations.

What I get using this approach is a reasonably customized container. Alas, there's a catch. The container at this point has been primed by `cloud-init` and it's a container instance, not an image/template.

So this is where I'm at a loss now. What I would need is to turn my container back into an image (should be doable by using `lxc publish`) and either undo the changes done to it by `cloud-init` or at least "cock" `cloud-init` again so it triggers the next time the image is used as source for `lxc init` or `lxc launch`. Alternatively, maybe there's a way to completely disable `cloud-init` when I `lxc launch` from the upstream image?

Is there an authoritative way? Even though I looked through all kinds of documentation, including the [Markdown documentation in the LXD repository](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/tree/master/doc) as well as the blog series by Stéphane Graber (LXD project lead), [especially [5/12]](https://stgraber.org/2016/03/30/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/), I was unable to find a suitable approach. Perhaps I just missed it (that's to say, I'll be happy to read through more documentation if you know some that describes what I need).

LXC version used is 2.20 (i.e. I'm using the LXD frontend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the linked [page [5/12]](https://stgraber.org/2016/03/30/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/) by Stéphane Graber, you can find a second approach:

> **Manually building an image**
>
> Building your own image is also pretty simple.
>
> 1. Generate a container filesystem. This entirely depends on the distribution you’re using. For Ubuntu and Debian, it would be by using
>    debootstrap.
> 2. Configure anything that’s needed for the distribution to work properly in a container (if anything is needed).
> 3. Make a tarball of that container filesystem, optionally compress it.
> 4. Write a new metadata.yaml file based on the one described above.
> 5. Create another tarball containing that metadata.yaml file.
> 6. Import those two tarballs as a LXD image with:

This way, you don't have to start the container, before you publish the image. You can start with an existing image:

```
$ lxc image copy ubuntu:16.04/amd64 local: --alias ubuntu
$ mkdir export-directory
$ lxc image export ubuntu export-directory
$ cd export-directory
$ ls 
5f364e2e3f460773a79e9bec2edb5e993d236f035f70267923d43ab22ae3bb62.squashfs
meta-5f364e2e3f460773a79e9bec2edb5e993d236f035f70267923d43ab22ae3bb62.tar.xz

$ mkdir meta squashfs
$ tar -xf *.tar.xz -D meta
$ sudo unsquashfs -f -d squash/ *squashfs
```

Now you can adjust files or even chroot into the squash directory. Then you can tar both directories and import the adjusted image with:

```
lxc image import <metadata tarball> <rootfs tarball> --alias my-adjusted-image
```

Comment: Thanks, but here's what I asked for: What I am looking for is an approach **to fashion an existing template** a way I'd like to. In particular what I'm after is **to customize the upstream Ubuntu cloud image** by making various changes in its root FS and adding/changing configuration.

Comment: I hope my update will address those requests.

Answer (score 2):

The main tool for building `lxd` / `lxc` images is [Distrobuilder](https://linuxcontainers.org/distrobuilder/docs/latest/)

The modern way to configure images is with [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

---

For customizing LXD / LXC images I wrote:

- [distrobuilder-menu](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu)

A python console frontend to Distrobuilder (which incorporates both)

[image: Distrobuilder Menu for LXD & LXC]

- [Features](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/README.md#arrow_right-features)

---

It follows a [similar methodology](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/README.md#-creating-override-templates) to Hashicorp Packer & builds templates in layers.

1. Create a `base` image that overrides a `standard` template &
   includes your `shell` & other customizations
2. Create a `custom` image override with your web services etc that overrides your `base` image (i.e use the `base` image template as a `SOURCE` template when generating a **custom template** with your custom service override / cloud-init config)

---

I use `dbmenu` for building unprivileged LXD containers & have added (& package) example configuration to create:

- Alpine Linux / Ubuntu `base` images with a few customizations
- Alpine Linux build environment with the `alpine-sdk` (& with `cloud-init` being removed on first boot)
- Ubuntu container that installs Gitlab on first boot (via cloud-init)

I also use `dbmenu` to create an Ubuntu image suitable for running `rootless` podman / docker inside `lxd` (at time of writing not yet added to the [examples](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/tree/main/examples))

---

- The [README](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/README.md) is quite complete now
- Ubuntu's LXD & the new [`incus`](https://github.com/lxc/incus) fork are both supported for building images
- See the [dependencies](https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/README.md#arrow_right-dependencies) needed by `dbmenu`. In **Oct 2023** you need the latest `git` version of `distrobuilder` to build the latest template format
- Under the hood `dbmenu` is using Mike Farah's `yq` to merge the `yaml` templates together (`yq` & `distrobuilder` are both written in `Go` so are both using the same underlying `yaml` library)
- Using `PyYaml` to merge was problematic - it reads & writes `yaml` configuration very fast with `yaml.CSafeLoader` for reading
- `dbmenu` installation is as simple as:
- `pipx install distrobuilder-menu` ([pypi - latest release](https://pypi.org/project/distrobuilder-menu/))
- `pipx install git+https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu.git` (github latest `dev` / release)

Comment: The way [_these days_ is distrobuilder](https://github.com/lxc/distrobuilder/commits/main?after=29e94ac90dc52ae4e5fc0c6ad34951d4369aa001+1540&branch=main&qualified_name=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain). Please mind the age of this question ...